# Passing Database Column Values to VB6 Function

Tags: function, vb6

I need to pass 8 database column dates to my CalculateMostRecentDate function since vb6 doesnt have a max function.  Am i simply able to pass the database values like this? or how would I do it?

```
Public Function CalculateMostRecentDate(ParamArray dates() As Variant) As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim MostRecentDate As Variant

MostRecentDate = dates(LBound(dates))
For i = LBound(dates) + 1 To UBound(dates)
    If MostRecentDate < dates(i) Then MostRecentDate = dates(i)
Next i
CalculateMostRecentDate = MostRecentDate
End Function
```

Call function within another function:

```
RECENT_APPRV_DT = CalculateMostRecentDate(EMPLOYER.UW_APPRV_DT,  EMPLOYER.BE_APPRV_DT, . . .)
```

Comment: What data type are your "database values"? Is EMPLOYER a recordset object?

Comment: its the datetime data type. and EMPLOYER is the table

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right.

Google turned up [this](http://www.visualbasic.happycodings.com/Applications-VBA/code8.html) which looks quite polished, also [this](https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/browse_thread/thread/c71d9fe313b7b0e5/96620098fd8d9d50?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=max+function#96620098fd8d9d50) from the old VB6 newsgroup.

Answer (score -1):

The function looks OK but you cannot call it the way you have indicated.  You will need to load the dates into an array and then pass the array in.